# Apache Drill Mongo DB simple query takes too long

Tags: mongodb, apache-drill

I am trying out Apache Drill to execute a query on a mongo connection. Simple `COUNT(1)` queries are taking too long. On the order of 20 seconds per query. When I try to connect using any other mongo connector and run the same query it takes miliseconds. I have also seen people talking online about their mongo queries taking 2 seconds. I can live with 2 seconds but 20 is too much.

Here is the query:

```
 select count(*) from mongo.test.contacts
```

Here is the Query Profile for the query.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some optimizations should be applied for your case. It will be very helpful if you will create a Jira ticket [1] with details:
DDL for MongoDB table, version of MongoDB and info from log files (because it is not clear what Drill did all this time).
Simple reproduce of your case can help to solve this issue more quickly.

Thanks.

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/DRILL/issues/